# Specify minimum memory requirement for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, memory, ram

My application requires at least 40MB of RAM, so earlier iPhones (like 3G, first iPod touch versions) just do not have it (they have max about 20MB for my app). Is there a proper way to disable installing it to 3G devices? I know UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, but it does not have parameter for minimum available memory.

Comment: Lol, you might want to rethink your code solution if you need that much memory at once. Plus voted so it gets more attention.

Comment: Ditto,LOL, 40Mb.. what's it do?  Think I'm right in saying iOS4 not supported on above devices, or at least first iPhone and first-gen iPod touch, so target app as this minumum OS version?

Comment: The application uses advanced specific 3rd party 3D graphics engine and I have no control over this. Use less memory is valid suggestion, but not so useful for me. My observaton is that iPhone 3G has more free memory (for apps) in 3.x OS version, than with 4.x versions, so minimum OS version is not really good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, are you sure that your application actually uses 40 MB of RAM on the older devices?  I've found (by using the Memory Monitor instrument) that the same application uses less RAM on my iPhone 3G than it does on my iPhone 4 or iPad.  The latter two devices have more pixels within their interfaces, so my application chews up more memory when running on them.

If it does, figure out if you can optimize memory usage to get it within a safe (< 30 MB) range for the older hardware.  If you can do this, I think you'll see an across-the-board performance improvement in your application, even on the newer hardware.

Finally, if you absolutely cannot run on an older iOS device, I'd recommend using the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities keys `armv7` or `opengles-2`.  Either will filter for the newer (iPhone 3G S and greater) hardware.  While not keyed on memory size, the iPhone 3G S launched with significantly more RAM than the older models, and not a device since has had less.  It's hard to imagine Apple reducing this specification at any point in the future.